# How to remove chart symbol from legend in ArcMap Desktop

Tags: charts, legend, pie-chart, arcmap

I am creating several maps for a client with pie charts as the symbology. However, in the legend there is an additional pie chart with a number after it. I have searched through the settings of both the legend and the data points, but cannot find an option to remove it. [Here is a picture of legend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Lub.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in the layout mode you can right click on the legend and select "Convert to Graphics" and then right click on the objects you wish to delete and select "Ungroup" then click on the object you wish to delete to remove them!